# OCR using MODI Office 2007

Tags: c#, ocr, office-2007, modi

hi i have problem to using OCR filtur from microsoft office 2007
i wanna create something like in [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10130/OCR-with-Microsoft-Office) tutorial 
in my laptop i already installed office 2007
but i can't find MODI (microsoft office document imaging 12.0 type library)

so far i already try to find it manualy in *C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MODI.*
but MODI folder not exist (weird because many article says that library come default if office 2007 installed)

then i try to download MODI libary from microsoft center. 
from [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982760) i try to install MODI library (method 1) but it's seems that is not MODI i want (not MDIVWCTL.DLL)

i wonder why in my laptop don't available MODI library although i already install office 2007? and where to get library to install it manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MODI is not installed by default in Office 2007. The link you're referring to deals with Office 2010. If you're using Vista or abvove, the following steps may help:

1. Exit all programs.
2. Click the Start button Button image, and then click Control Panel.
3. In Control Panel, click Programs, and then click Programs and Features.
4. Right-click the name of the Microsoft Office edition that you installed or right-click Microsoft Office Word 2007 (depending on whether you installed Word as part of Office or as an individual program), and then click Change.
5. Click Add or Remove Features, and then click Continue.
6. Under Installation Options, click the plus sign (+) next to Office Tools.
7. Click the arrow next to Microsoft Office Document Imaging, click Run all from my Computer, and then click Continue.

More details can be gathered [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/word-help/scan-and-edit-a-document-HA010254879.aspx#BM1).